# wordpress navaigation and menu wont display properly when user visit my site live magazine theme by templatic themes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive

when i am logged in as admin my site display this way

this is how it looks like when aii am logged in as admin as show in the first image

[image: this is how it looks like when aii am logged in as admin as show in the first image]

but when a visitor or when not logged in its display this way, as shown in the image second image

[image: but when a visitor or when not logged in its display this way, as shown in the image second image]

Please what could be the problem.

Comment: please click on the description to view the image...i was having problem posting and making the image visible at a glance. your comment is very important thank you.

Comment: Try to disable the plugins one by one, if you have any caching plugin try to disable it... also make a backup of the site then delete this directory "wp-content/cache"   delete the cache folder then see whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like missing styles. You can check your console and see if something is missing.
Also there might be a problem with menu being out of its place due to some error. That means the styles don't point to it properly.
Other problems can cause such problems, if you could check some codes or put some of the codes here we could help more sufficiently.